# Get parent constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype

If you have this code :

```
var myError = new Error('error !');
console.log(myError instanceof Error); // true
console.log(myError.stack instanceof Error); // false
console.log(myError.constructor.name); // Error
console.log(myError.stack.constructor.name); // String
```

- How can you access the constructor name (Error) of the parent (myError) of myError.stack ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... You want to get the constructor name of the parent of `myError.stack`, which is `myError`, but you're already doing it. JavaScript is a prototype based language, so Error is not inheriting from a parent in the way classes inherit from parent classes in other languages.

Comment: The `stack` property is a plain String, so there is no way to get back to the error object? Not sure why you would need this.

Comment: what do you mean by "parent"?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to get the "parent" object from a property value. (What if a value was contained in two objects?) The only way would be if you had some circular reference between them (like between `constructor` and `prototype`), but this is definitely not the case for your `myError.stack` string.